# Subtracting 2 arrays of different sizes using for-loop

Tags: python, for-loop, subtraction

I'm trying to subtract values in 2 data frames, excluding the first digit of the second df `y2` using a `for` loop (to bypass the *'shape error'* of having two different-sized arrays).

```py
difference = []
for i in range(0, len(y2)):
    difference.append(y2[i-1] - y1[i])
print(difference)
```

For example, instead of having

```
  0 1 2 3
- 0 1 2 3
= [0,0,0]
```

I want

```
  0 1 2 3
-   0 1 2 3
= [1,1,1]
```

I'm using `range(0, len(y2))` to select the first index of df `y2`, and subtract df `y2` by df `y1`. However, I'm not getting any results in my variable explorer tab.

[image: output]

Comment: Feel like providing a hint (and say, a tag) for the language used :)?

Comment: Oh thanks, lol. Using python.

Comment: It's just `diff = [x-y for x,y in zip(y2[1:],y1[:-1])]`

Comment: note that when `i==0`, `y2[i-1]` will be `y2[-1]`, which gets the last element of the list. You should start your range at 1 and then do `y2[i] - y1[i-1]`

Comment: The screendshot says that `y1` and `y2` are dataframes, not lists. If this is pandas then the solution will be different.

Comment: Yes, I'm using pandas. The solution above gives me: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Of course.  You said lists so we gave solutions that work with lists, not dataframes.

Comment: I'm not a pandas expert, but something like `difference = y2.loc[1:, 'n800'] - y1.loc[:-1, 'n900']`